# AWS api gateway returning token in the response body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I noticed something weird when calling my service on a URL like this

```
GET https://myservice.com//someresource
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-api-key:<somekey>' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <sometoken>
```

When I do this, I get a response from AWS gateway that includes  in the response body

```
< HTTP/2 403
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 3222
< x-amzn-requestid: 348fab78-b84d-4af9-88v9-e1e6effc487b
< x-amzn-errortype: IncompleteSignatureException
< x-amz-apigw-id: dgYbMFbhliAFv8w=
<
* Connection #0 to host myservice.com left intact
{"message":"<sometoken>"}
```

Calling https://myservice.com/someresource , without the extra slash, works ok. I know that // is not a correct path but I would like that the response message reflect the fact that the path is wrong instead of returning my token in a 403 response.
Is there any setting to configure this behaviour?